# VueJs Teleport To Style - Script Tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-teleport

I want the admin to be able to use their own custom codes on the site such as Google Analytic code. So I try to use teleport to `script` and `style` tag like this;

Index.html;

```
<script id="custom-js"></script>
<style id="custom-css"></style>
```

App.vue;

```
<teleport to="#custom-css" v-html="custom.css"></teleport>
<teleport to="#custom-js" v-html="custom.js"></teleport>
```

But it's not working. What can I do? Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is `v-html` accepts `string` only, not a file path, `v-html` is mostly like `innerHTML` attribute of the DOM element.